# Error with SqlSysClrTypes.msi when trying to install my application in C # and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application developed in C# with SQL Server 2014 and I have the database included in the project.

When I install the program on my PC, I have no problems and the program works correctly.

The error appears when trying to install the application on the client with Windows 7; the download of necessary files begins until at a moment it throws the error

> The setup has detected that the file c: //...route..//SqlsysClrTypes.msi has changed since it was initially published.

and after this message the installation is canceled.

I found that maybe the error is due to the version of `SqlServer.Types.dll` is different from the one installed in the OS, in the program the version I have is 12.0.0.0 but I can not find the one in the OS. The path to verify the `SqlSysClrTypes` version in the windows registry is:

```
HKLM \ SOFTWARE \ Wow6432Node \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Uninstall {718FFB65-F6E4-4D62-861F-ED10ED32C936}
```

I thought about updating the version I have in my application in some way, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I discovered that the error appeared because I initially accessed the database that I created in my instance of Sql Server installed on my laptop but then tried to change to a database incorporated into the project, made all the necessary modifications and the program It works correctly but when I try to install it on the client it throws this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to the fact that in the prerequisites of the installer I had selected (in addition to the necessary framework) the files of `SqlsysClrTypes`. So I deselected these files and I was able to install the program on the client without problems.